# How to find the module name to import in Java?

Tags: java

For example, I would like to use SimpleDateFormat in my Java file and I located the document in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
java.text
Class SimpleDateFormat

java.lang.Object
    java.text.Format
       java.text.DateFormat
            java.text.SimpleDateFormat
All Implemented Interfaces:
Serializable, Cloneable
```

Which name should I use in `import ***`? And generally(maybe other modules) which line should I use?

Comment: Just read [this official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)

Comment: `import java.text.SimpleDateFormat`, because it's the class your are interested, the rest shows what it inheritates from...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using any IDE for development then you don't need to worry about it. But if you are using any text editor then you should `import only those classes which are needed` in your code.

Like you said you want to use SimpleDateFormat, then you can import `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` or `java.text.DateFormat` which is an abstract class and is going to implements in `SimpleDateFormat`.

Remember : Java's *import* statement is pure syntactical sugar. import is only evaluated at compile time to indicate to the compiler where to find the names in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the name if the correspoding class which you want to use otherwise you can also import all classes by using `import java.text.*`  otherwise `import java.text.SimpleDateFormat`

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the link provided, you will see

```
java.lang.Object
  java.text.Format
    java.text.DateFormat
      java.text.SimpleDateFormat
```

Copy and pate `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` as

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the classname with complete package hierarchy. So in your case, you need to import:

```
        java.text.SimpleDateFormat
```

where `SimpleDateFormat` is the classname and `java.text` is the package

**Note**: Using an IDE such as eclipse, can help you save a lot of time for organizing your imports.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a problem? It's very clear:java.text.SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 0):

For an example,If you need to use `SimpleDateFormat`, use as below.

`SimpleDateFormat` class is belongs to `java.text` package.

so you have import as below.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)

> To import a specific member into the current file, put an import statement at the beginning of the file before any type definitions but after the package statement, if there is one. Here's how you would import the Rectangle class from the graphics package created in the previous section.

```
import graphics.Rectangle;
```

So in your Case:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
```